# Error Code '{' Expected in BlueJ

Tags: bluej

I'm trying to help my son with a High School coding class and we just can't figure this problem.  I've been able to fix the other coding problems but can't find any answers (even through web) about fixing this particular one.

Here is the coding formula:

```
/**
* Write a description of class Tia here.
*
* @author (your name)
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/

import objectdraw.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AlexisSmile extends FrameWindowController (Error message: '{' Expected)

    FilledOval head = new FilledOval (100,100,200, 200, canvas);
    FilledOval eyeR = new FilledOval (130, 130, 70, 60, canvas);
    FilledOval eyeL = new FilledOval (200, 130, 70, 60, canvas);
    FilledOval pupilR = new FilledOval (150, 130, 50, 40, canvas);
    FilledOval pupilL = new FilledOval (220, 130, 50, 40, canvas);
    FilledArc mouth = new FilledArc (150, 100, 100, 200, 0, -180, canvas);
    FilledArc insideMouth = new FilledArc (160, 115, 80, 0, -180, canvas);

    /**
    * This changes the color of the different shapes for the smiley face.
    */
    public void begin()
    {
        head.setColor(Color.yellow);
        pupilR.setColor(Color.red);
        pupilL.setColor(Color.red);
        insideMouth.setColor(Color.pink);
    } 


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this -> `(Error message: '{' Expected)` is a syntax error(unless it some sort of bluej thing). Try replasing it with a `{`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with bluej, but it seems like it's trying to tell you that you forgot an opening `{` after the `class` name.

**THIS:**

```
/**
* Write a description of class Tia here.
*
* @author (your name)
* @version (a version number or a date)
*/

import objectdraw.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class AlexisSmile extends FrameWindowController {

    FilledOval head = new FilledOval (100,100,200, 200, canvas);
    FilledOval eyeR = new FilledOval (130, 130, 70, 60, canvas);
    FilledOval eyeL = new FilledOval (200, 130, 70, 60, canvas);
    FilledOval pupilR = new FilledOval (150, 130, 50, 40, canvas);
    FilledOval pupilL = new FilledOval (220, 130, 50, 40, canvas);
    FilledArc mouth = new FilledArc (150, 100, 100, 200, 0, -180, canvas);
    FilledArc insideMouth = new FilledArc (160, 115, 80, 0, -180, canvas);

    /**
    * This changes the color of the different shapes for the smiley face.
    */
    public void begin()
    {
        head.setColor(Color.yellow);
        pupilR.setColor(Color.red);
        pupilL.setColor(Color.red);
        insideMouth.setColor(Color.pink);
    } 

}
```

should solve the syntax error.

I also noticed that you pass `canvas` into methods but the is no declaration for it... so the next error will probably be that `canvas can not be resolved`. I can assume that it should be an instance of `java.awt.Canvas` but you need to declare and instantiate it.